# What does "new world order" mean grammatically?

Tags: meaning

> New World Order

Does it mean "order of the new world" or "New order of the world"? I skimmed through Wikipedia, but it's unclear. I am not looking for the correct meaning based on the concept itself, but just looking for the meaning that is correct in terms of grammar. Is it context-dependent or is there a clear grammar rule to interpret this kind of words?

Comment: Wikipedia has 2 big pages related to that term, one as "politics" and one as "conspiracy theory". Just skimming is not enough. We are not here to read it for you. You are welcome to ask specific questions about details.

Comment: @virolino Without any context, which meaning is correct grammatically?

Comment: Without any context, it's ambiguous. It means both—or neither. It's no different than asking what *drunk* means. Nobody can tell you unless you put it into a sentence. (Or unless you want to list every possible meaning, like a dictionary does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be understood in two ways (at least):

> Order for the (New World)

or

> (New Order) for the World

or (more extreme?):

> (New Order) for a (New World)

Comment: Then it is context-dependent, right?

Comment: What is context dependent? The expression "New World Order" is the shortened form of a longer expression. However, I am not sure which is the "original" expression - if there was ever one.